CA workload automation dSeries - Security Report Query
We are trying to get to the data for the "canned" security report so we can integrate it into our centralized reporting.  We have the main table for the data, however the Access Values are not within the table.  Does anyone know where they are?
We have reviewed all tables and views in the data structure.
